# problems passing data from a recycleView to another

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, interface, android-recyclerview

I'm a beginner on Android development and I was trying to make a simple app that has a recycleView inside a fragment using cardViews and when you click the like button inside of any of the items inside the list, the app then should send this item to another fragment called FavoriteFragment (which also contains recycleView) and display it here.

I tried to use an interface to do this, but whenever I click one of the like buttons, my activity does not receive the information (I tried to Log.d a message inside the method and is not being displayed)

here is the code for each of this:

My interface, what I am trying to use to pass the data from countries fragment-> adapter -> viewholder -> activity -> favorite fragment

```
public interface InterfaceListItemClickListener {
void listItemClickAction(ArrayList properties);
}
```

my CountriesFragment, which is the fragment that holds the first RecycleView:

```
public class CountriesFragment extends Fragment {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

ArrayList<RecycleViewItem> listCountries = new ArrayList<>();
String names[] = {"Thailand", "Venezuela", "Sweden"};
int images[] = {R.drawable.thailand, R.drawable.venezuela, R.drawable.sweden};
RecyclerView myRecyclerView;

InterfaceListItemClickListener sender;

public CountriesFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    sender = (InterfaceListItemClickListener) getActivity();
}

public static CountriesFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    CountriesFragment fragment = new CountriesFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
    initializeList();
}

public void initializeList(){
    listCountries.clear();
    for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
        RecycleViewItem item = new RecycleViewItem();
        item.setCardName(names[i]);
        item.setImageResourceID(images[i]);
        item.setIsFav(0);
        item.setIsTurned(0);
        listCountries.add(item);
    }
}





@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_countries, container, false);

    myRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycleView);
    myRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager myLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    myLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    ListsForFragments.populateCountriesList();
    if (ListsForFragments.countriesList.size() > 0 & myRecyclerView != null) {
        myRecyclerView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(ListsForFragments.countriesList, sender));
    }
    myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(myLayoutManager);
    return view;
}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
```

}

My Adapter class:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder>{
private ArrayList<RecycleViewItem> list = new ArrayList<RecycleViewItem>();

InterfaceListItemClickListener sender = null;

public MyAdapter(ArrayList<RecycleViewItem> list, InterfaceListItemClickListener sender) {
    this.list = list;
    this.sender = sender;
}

public MyAdapter(ArrayList<RecycleViewItem> list) {
    this.list = list;
}




@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycle_items, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view, sender);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.titleTextView.setText(list.get(position).getCardName());
    holder.coverImageView.setImageResource(list.get(position).getImageResourceID());
    holder.coverImageView.setTag(list.get(position).getImageResourceID());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}
 }
```

My viewHolder class:

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

public TextView titleTextView;
public ImageView coverImageView;
public ImageView likeImageView;
public ImageView shareImageView;


public ImageView favoriteImageView;
public TextView favoriteTextView;

private ArrayList goesToFavourites = new ArrayList();
public MyViewHolder(View itemView, final InterfaceListItemClickListener sender) {
    super(itemView);
    titleTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
    coverImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.coverImageView);
    likeImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.likeImageView);
    shareImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.shareImageView);

    favoriteImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_favorite);
    favoriteTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_name_favorite);
    if (likeImageView != null) {
        likeImageView.setTag(R.drawable.ic_like);
        likeImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int id = (int) likeImageView.getTag();
                if (id == R.drawable.ic_like) {
                    likeImageView.setTag(R.drawable.ic_liked);
                    likeImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_liked);
                    if(sender != null) {
                        getGoesToFavourites().add(coverImageView);
                        getGoesToFavourites().add(likeImageView);
                        sender.listItemClickAction(getGoesToFavourites());
                    }
                } else {
                    likeImageView.setTag(R.drawable.ic_like);
                    likeImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_like);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

public ArrayList getGoesToFavourites() {
    return goesToFavourites;
}

public void setGoesToFavourites(ArrayList goesToFavourites) {
    this.goesToFavourites = goesToFavourites;
}
}
```

My favoriteFragment class, the one receiving the information:

```
public class FavoriteFragment extends Fragment {
private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

RecyclerView myRecyclerView;
ArrayList receiver = new ArrayList();

public FavoriteFragment() {

}

public void receiveData(ArrayList receiver){
    this.receiver = receiver;
}


public static FavoriteFragment newInstance() {
    FavoriteFragment fragment = new FavoriteFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_favorite, container, false);

    myRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycleView);
    myRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager myLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    myLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    if (receiver != null & myRecyclerView != null) {
        myRecyclerView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(receiver));
    }
    myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(myLayoutManager);
    return view;    }

public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
}
```

finally, my MainActivity, the bridge:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        HostFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        CountriesFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        CitiesFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        PlacesFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        FavoriteFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        ViewPagerFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        InterfaceListItemClickListener{

FragmentManager fm;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

    //if this is the first time we are running the app
    if(savedInstanceState ==  null){
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.content, new ViewPagerFragment());
        transaction.commit();
    }
}

@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

}

@Override
public void listItemClickAction(ArrayList list) {
    FavoriteFragment favorite = (FavoriteFragment) 
fm.findFragmentById(R.id.favorite);
    favorite.receiveData(list);
    Log.d("INTERFACE", "Data received!" + list);
}
}
```

If any extra information needed let me know and I'll provide.

EDIT: so trying to debug, I found out that the InterfaceListItemClickListener that MyViewHolder is a null, but not sure why...

EDIT 2: so I changed some things, inside My CountriesFragment:

- I deleted the OnActivityCreated method and initialized the interface rather inside the onCreate like this:

  ```
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  initializeList();
  sender = (InterfaceListItemClickListener) getActivity();
  }
  ```

Now with this change, I was able to know that the findFragmentById inside my MainActivity is returning me a null. now, the way I am displaying this fragment is by using a ViewPager fragment which holds both fragments. this looks like this:

```
public class ViewPagerFragment extends Fragment {


private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public static ViewPager viewPager;

public ViewPagerFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public static ViewPagerFragment newInstance() {
    ViewPagerFragment fragment = new ViewPagerFragment();
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getActivity().setTitle(null);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_pager, container, false);
    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()); //getChildFragmentManager
    viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    return view;
}


public class CustomAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


    public CustomAdapter(FragmentManager fm){
        super(fm);

    }

    //position tells the program what fragment we are currently on/displaying
    public Fragment getItem(int position){
        switch (position){ //notice we don't use breaks on each case, due to the return statement on each.
            case 0:return CountriesFragment.newInstance();
            case 1: return FavoriteFragment.newInstance();
            default: return FavoriteFragment.newInstance();
        }
    }

    public  int getCount(){
        return 2;
    }

}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
}
```

How would I proceed in this case to finish passing the information?

Answer (score 0):

`OnCreateView()` is called before `OnActivityCreate()` thats why your sender is null.Moreover,you must avoid setting or creating any objects in the OnCreateView(). Your fragment should be like this

```
public class CountriesFragment extends Fragment {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

ArrayList<RecycleViewItem> listCountries = new ArrayList<>();
String names[] = {"Thailand", "Venezuela", "Sweden"};
int images[] = {R.drawable.thailand, R.drawable.venezuela, R.drawable.sweden};
RecyclerView myRecyclerView;

InterfaceListItemClickListener sender;

public CountriesFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    sender = (InterfaceListItemClickListener) getActivity();
 myRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager myLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    myLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    ListsForFragments.populateCountriesList();
    if (ListsForFragments.countriesList.size() > 0 & myRecyclerView != null) {
        myRecyclerView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(ListsForFragments.countriesList, sender));
    }
    myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(myLayoutManager);
}

public static CountriesFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    CountriesFragment fragment = new CountriesFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
    initializeList();
}

public void initializeList(){
    listCountries.clear();
    for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
        RecycleViewItem item = new RecycleViewItem();
        item.setCardName(names[i]);
        item.setImageResourceID(images[i]);
        item.setIsFav(0);
        item.setIsTurned(0);
        listCountries.add(item);
    }
}





@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_countries, container, false);

    myRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycleView);

    return view;
}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you I changed to this way, I did not know about which gets called first I am going to look into the fragment lifecycle. Also, I added a second edit to my question, in which when I receive the information inside my MainActivity, I can't send it back to the next fragment. Thanks

Comment: You can find the fragment as it is not attached to your activity but your ViewPagerFragment. You have to call getItem on your viewPager to get the fragment